# How to move expanded table row in mat-table over to the right with css

Tags: css, angular, mat-table

I have been following an example of adding expandable rows to an angular mat-table. So far, I have been successful - my code works mostly like the example. However, I am having a CSS issue. My expandable row is offset too far to the left, I am wondering how to shift it more to the right. Additionally, I would like to add rows to the expandable portion, instead of using mat-list. I have included an image of what I currently have and an image of what I would like to have. I am using Angular 9 and typescript for this project.

Example Link: https://www.freakyjolly.com/expand-collapse-single-or-multiple-rows-in-angular-98-material-table-multiple-single/

**My question is, how can I shift the expandable table rows more to the right?**

[current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zuone.png)
[desired table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQxcV.png)

Notice in how the desired table, the list of extra rooms lines up with the column name (room info).

Below is my HTML file

```
<mat-card class="table">
<mat-card-header>
<mat-card-title> Home Information </mat-card-title>
</mat-card-header>

<mat-card-content>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="homeData" multiTemplateDataRows>

<ng-container matColumnDef="houseNumber">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> House Number> </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.homeNumber}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="houseStreet">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> House Street> </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.homeStreet}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="roomInfo">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Room Info> </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
      <span *ngIf="element.extraRooms; else noMoreRooms">
      <a mat-button href="javascript:void(0)" click()="element.isExpanded =! element.isExpanded">Peek></a>
      </span>
      <ng-template #noMoreRooms> </ng-template>
   </td>
</ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="listOfExtraRooms.length">

        <div class="row student-element-detail" [@detailExpand]="element.isExpanded ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
          <mat-list>
            <mat-list-item *ngFor="let list of listOfExtraRooms">
            <span *ngIf="element.houseNumber === list.houseNumber">
             <tr>
               <span> {{list.roomName}} </span>
             </tr>
            </mat-list-item>
          </mat-list>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;" class="student-element-row" [class.student-expanded-row]="element.isExpanded"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="student-detail-row"></tr>

</table>
</mat-card-content>
```

Below is my CSS file

```
.mat-list-item {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.student-element-detail {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 3px 8px #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.student-element-row td {
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}

td.mat-cell {
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

th.mat-header-cell {
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

.margin {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Below is my typescript (ts) file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0' })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {


  houseJSON = [
   {
     "homeNumber": "1827",
     "homeStreet": "Paris_Road",
     "extraRooms": true
   }
   ];

  listOfExtraRooms = [
   {
     "homeNumber": "1827",
     "roomName": "kitchen",
     "isExpanded": false,
   },
   {
     "homeNumber": "1827",
     "roomName": "bathroom",
     "isExpanded": false,
   }
  ];


  dataHouseList = new MatTableDataSource();
  displayedColumns = string[] = ['houseNumber', 'houseStreet',  'roomInfo'];

  ngOnInit() {
   this.dataHouseList.data = this.houseJSON;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you still looking for solution for it ?